# Effect Size Calculation on Conversion Rates of A/B Testing

Tags: r, ab-testing

Trying to measure how likely an experiment group performed better than control group in conversion rate.

Business context:
 1. Sample size: 80000,
 2. Samples: 2,
 3. Sample A converted: 1800,
 4. Sample B converted: 1896,
 5. Significant level: 0.05

I am trying to figure out how to get d to calculate power in qwr package in r:

Here is my code:

```
pwr.t.test(
      n=80000,
      d=???,
      sig.level = 0.05,
      power=NULL,
      type = "two.sample",
      alternative = "two.sided"
      )
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to give it a value for `power` for it to give you an effect size. At power of `0.8` the effect size is `0.014`.

Comment: What if I want to calculate the power, how can I get the effect size number from observations?

Answer (score 0):

```
h=ES.h(0.212,0.02)
#I think this will work.
#And use:
 pwr.p.test(
  n=80000,
  h=0.00844915,
  sig.level = 0.05,
  power=NULL,     
   alternative = "greater"
 )
```

This link accidentally answered my question:
[Sample size and power calculation in r as viable alternative to proc power in SAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395767/sample-size-and-power-calculation-in-r-as-viable-alternative-to-proc-power-in-sa?rq=1)